# Can no longer use iPhone with XCode for testing, iPhone OS is a newer version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have XCode 4.6.2, and on my iPhone I now have iOS 6.1.3. When I plug my iPhone into my Mac, XCode doesn't let me select it as an option for testing, as my project settings are to work on 6.1, and the dropdown doesn't have any newer options. I went into preferences, and the only available downloads are past versions of the simulator.

How do I get XCode to allow me to test using 6.1.3?

Comment: What's wrong with using 6.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Organizer from Xcode,in that devices, find your device and click the option to use for development